# UI for rating an app during deletion

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4, app-store-connect

Is that possible pop up the UI which comes during the deletion process before deleting the app ? (A UI which has stars, no thanks, rate my app button).

If no, can you tell me whether it is possible to create a screen and send the rating captured to iTunes connect ?

Comment: Note that this rate-on-delete dialog was removed in iOS 4.0, for good reason.

Answer (score 4):

As other people said, your best option is to send people to the review/ratings page on iTunes.

The best open source solution I found for this is [Appirater](https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/).

I use it in my apps and it works great + it generates many reviews.

You can configure when the popup should show. It basically looks like this:

[image: Appirater preview]
<sub>(source: [arashpayan.com](http://arashpayan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/AppiraterScreenshot.png))</sub>

It was created by *Arash Payan*, visit his page about [Appirater](https://arashpayan.com/blog/index.php/2009/09/07/presenting-appirater/) with all the information.

Answer (score 0):

This form always pops up if you delete an app on your iPhone. I don't think you can grab personal ratings out of iTunes but once you gather a sufficient number of votes you'll see the details on your app iTunes page.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot present this UI yourself—it's handled by the OS. You can, however, direct your users to your app's rating page in the App Store app by opening an appropriate iTunes store URL, as documented in the “Heading straight to a review form” section of [this article](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/).

Comment: what are the parameters that can be send to the review form ? Is there a way to get the ratings inside the app and then send it to review form with those values ?

Comment: The only parameter it takes is the ID of your application. No, your app can't send the rating itself—why would Apple allow that?