# How to Add "Write a Review" / "Rate Us" Feature to My App?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, popup, review

I wish to add some sort of a "Write a Review" or "Rate Us" feature to my app so my customers can easily rate and review my app.

Best practice I can think of is to have some sort of pop-up or open a UIWebView within my app so the user is not kicked off of my app while opening the App Store application as done in:

**[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"itms://itunes.com/apps/myAppName"]];**

Does anyone knows of a way to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alert a user to rate an application from iTunes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3011246/alert-a-user-to-rate-an-application-from-itunes)

Comment: See also [Alert for reminding the user to rate the app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639619/alert-for-reminding-the-user-to-rate-the-app)

Answer (score 89, accepted):

## StoreKit API (iOS 10.3 and up)

As of iOS 10.3, the StoreKit API provides a way to request a review on the App Store without leaving your app. When called, the system may present the user with an alert that requests a review. The user may provide a star rating directly inside the alert, continue on to write a review, or dismiss the alert. StoreKit handles just about everything for you. To present the review request, make the following call where it is appropriate in your app:

```
// Objective-C
[SKStoreReviewController requestReview]

// Swift
SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
```

As per Apple's instructions, you should not call these in response to a direct user-interaction (i.e. tapping a button that says "Write a Review") because it may not always display the alert. Indeed, the alert may only be displayed three times every 365 days.

> **Important Note**: Although this seems fairly simple, you'll still need to write some kind of logic in order to space out your prompts. For example, to present the prompt only after X number of launches, days, or significant events.
>
> If you fail to do this and just stick the review prompt anywhere (a `viewDidAppear` call, for example), your users will be rather annoyed because they'll see it pretty quickly and repeatedly. Then, either they leave a bad review (because they're annoyed) or aren't asked to review again for a whole year.

Below is an example of what the alert looks like. For more information, see [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/ratings-and-reviews/).

[image: StoreKit rating / review prompt.]

---

## iRate (iOS 7.0 and up)

If your app runs on versions of iOS earlier than 10.3 *or* you need more robust control over requesting ratings from users, iRate is a good solution.

For devices with iOS 10.3 or greater, iRate uses the aforementioned StoreKit API. For devices running iOS 7.0 to 10.2, iRate uses a [uialertview](/questions/tagged/uialertview) and [storekit](/questions/tagged/storekit) to ask the user for a rating (or to remind them later). Everything is customizable, from the title of the Cancel button to the interval at which it reminds the user.

By default, iRate automatically opens when certain requirements are met (e.g. app launched X number of times, user passed X number of levels), but you can also use a variety of methods and your own logic (with the help of iRate methods) to manually display an iRate popup.

#### Setup

To install, just drag the header file, the implementation file, and the `.bundle` (for localization) into your project.

1. Import the header in your AppDelegate: `#import "iRate.h"`
2. Add the **StoreKit** Framework to your project - More on [StoreKit from Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/StoreKit_Collection/_index.html)
3. In your `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method, set the following:

   ```
   // Configure iRate
   [iRate sharedInstance].daysUntilPrompt = 5;
   [iRate sharedInstance].usesUntilPrompt = 15;
   ```

#### Properties

The property below is useful for testing purposes. Set it to `YES` during testing to make sure the dialog appears properly. When set to `YES` it will appear immediately on startup, disregarding other display settings. Set this to `NO` for release versions of your app.

```
 [iRate sharedInstance].previewMode = NO;
```

The `appStoreID` property allows you to set the ID of your app. This is *only required if you have both Mac and iOS apps with the same Bundle Identifier*. The App ID set here must also match the Bundle ID set in Xcode and iTunes Connect:

```
[iRate sharedInstance].appStoreID = 555555555;
```

[More Details](https://github.com/nicklockwood/iRate) are available on the iRate GitHub page.

Comment: FYI, the latest version of iRate doesn't require the [iRate sharedInstance].appStoreID any more - it works automatically using the bundle ID in your Info.plist file.

Comment: Can this one redirect user to Review tab of Appstore page in IOS 7 too ? If is there any chance of this thing then please post answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/q/25138525/2225439

Answer (score 7):

A really good one I use is Appirater: https://github.com/arashpayan/appirater/

It automatically prompts your users to leave reviews, you just have to provide your app id.

Answer (score 1):

[image]**Declare Variable**

let reviewService = ReviewService.shared

**In View Did Appear**

self.reviewService.rateAlert(from: self)

**Import the Class**

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class ReviewService: NSObject {
    
    static let shared = ReviewService()
    
    private var lastRequest : Date? {
        
        get {
            
            return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "lastRequest") as? Date
        }
        set {
            
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "lastRequest")
        }
    }
    
    private var oneDayAgo : Date {
        
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: Date()) ?? Date()
    }
    
    private var shouldReview : Bool {
        if lastRequest == nil {
            return true
        }
        else if let lastRequest = self.lastRequest , lastRequest < oneDayAgo {
            return true
        }
        else {
            
            return false
        }
    }
    
    func requestReview(isWrittenReview : Bool = false) {
        
        if isWrittenReview {
            let appID = "##########" // App Id
            
            let urlStr = "https://itunes.apple.com/app/id\(appID)?action=write-review"
            
            guard let url = URL(string: urlStr), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) else { return }
            
            UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
        }
        else {
            SKStoreReviewController.requestReview()
        }
        
    }
    
    //MARK:- Rate App
    func rateAlert(from : UIViewController?) {
        
        guard shouldReview else {
            print("Don't Show")
            return
        }
        
        guard let vc = from else {
            
            return
        }
        
        lastRequest = Date()
        
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Rate our App", message: "If you love our app, please take a moment to rate it in the App Store", preferredStyle: .alert)
        
        
        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "Rate", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction?) -> Void in
            
            self.requestReview(isWrittenReview: false)
            
        })
        
        let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "Send Feedback", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction?) -> Void in
            
            self.requestReview(isWrittenReview: true)
            
        })
        
        let action3 = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: .default, handler: nil)
        
        alert.addAction(action1)
        alert.addAction(action2)
        alert.addAction(action3)
        vc.present(alert,animated: true)
        
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my tiny wrapper around SKStoreReviewController.

```
// Review after 3 launches
AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3)

// Review after 5 days
AppReview.requestIf(days: 5)

// Review after 3 launches and 5 days
AppReview.requestIf(launches: 3, days: 5)
```

https://github.com/mezhevikin/AppReview