# can i rate and review my app within my app or without open app store?

Tags: ios, app-store

**1) My Client said to me without open the app store directly give rate and review using custom Rate And Review the App.**

Is it Possible to rate and review the app without open the app store page?

**2) I have a two App 'A' and 'B' i want to redirect My App 'A' to 'B' is it Possible?**

Comment: Checkout [this](http://www.memention.com/blog/2009/09/03/Open-Reviews.html) tutorial. It´s in Objective-C but it will give you a hint of how to solve your issue.

Comment: You can rate your app with out opening App Store app. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6736189/how-to-add-write-a-review-rate-us-feature-to-my-app?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

1. My Client said to me without open the app store directly give rate
   and review using custom Rate And Review the App.

> > No, it is not possible, rating and add reviews can only be done through App Store.

2. I have a two App 'A' and 'B' i want to redirect My App 'A' to 'B' is
   it Possible?

> > Using URL Schemes you can open one app from another for more info check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone) link

Comment: any Apple Document about Rate and Review Page for restriction?