# Asking for Reviews from within an app

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, itunes

In my published app, I wish to give the user a button that will open the `iTunes` page for the app, and navigate to the `Add a Review` section for the app.

Is it possible to create a url to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Direct "rate in iTunes" link in my app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654144/direct-rate-in-itunes-link-in-my-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. [Read this article](http://bjango.com/articles/ituneslinks/).
In short, your URL will look like this:

```
itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=337064413
```

You'll have to replace the id with your App's id.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. For example, an angry birds link:

http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds/id343200656?mt=8

That would open the app store for that app.

It would have to be a link from your website, however, as you wouldn't have that link until after you submitted the app to apple for review...

So, on your server:

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="refresh" CONTENT="seconds;URL=link-to-my-application">
    </HEAD>
</HTML>
```

Or just use a short link service like [bit.ly](http://bit.ly) and change the link once your app has been reviewed.