# Can iOS app rating be tested before your app is live?

Tags: ios, app-store

Just a sanity check here. If I have an app and add a "Rate Me" button, redirecting the request as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654144/direct-rate-in-itunes-link-in-my-app), is it possible to test this before the first version of the app is live (other than pointing it at a different app)? Is there a definitive source for an answer?

Comment: No, this cannot be tested, as long as you are passing the correct id, it will be good to you. :)