# Create iOS link to an App in the app store - best way?

Tags: ios, url, app-store, hyperlink

Here are my requirements:

  1. Create links to a single app in the app store

  2. Access the links either from inside an app, on the device generally (e.g. mail link) or from a PC (e.g. via facebook share link)

  3. Open links using
  `iPhone`
  or
  `iPad`
  running
  `iOS 5`
  +

I have done some digging around and come up with the following options:

```
http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=487547243

http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/anyValue/id487547243?mt=8

http://itunes.com/apps/seligmanVenturesLtd/mouseTrapFree

http://itunes.com/apps/mouseTrapFree

itms://itunes.com/apps/mouseTrapFree

itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/mouseTrapFree
```

Just wondering if one (or some) of these are better than other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ok, so have done a lot of research/testing and here is my conclusion:

1. Links you use in your code should not rely on the 'current' name of you app, since this might change over time (e.g. Light Alarm Lite vs Light Alarm Free). Therefore the following 4 are out IMHO:
   http://itunes.com/apps/seligmanVenturesLtd/mouseTrapFree
   http://itunes.com/apps/mouseTrapFree
   itms://itunes.com/apps/mouseTrapFree
   itms-apps://itunes.com/apps/mouseTrapFree
2. That leaves itunes and phobos URLs. I have just tested both URLs via the iOS 6 share functionality (so this might be different on iOS 5, but given numbers are reducing daily for that I dont really mind). I tested accessing via SMS, Email, Facebook, Twitter (on an iPhone 5 and using a Mac).

Both url types produced near identical results, except for the following:

**Phobos:**
e.g. http://phobos.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=346542660
+ None
- Sharing this link on facebook created a facebook link without any image... this was the showstopper for me that will mean I use iTunes urls going forward (see below).

**iTunes**
e.g. http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/appName/id346542660?mt=8
+ When opening link on iphone 'Mail' app the app store opened within the 'Mail' app and no tabs along the bottom appeared, so arguably this creates increased focus on your app
- None

In summary, I will be going with itunes type urls going forward. eg:
e.g. http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/appName/id346542660?mt=8
(Note: you don't have to stipulate the '/appName' in this url, just keeping it as '/appName/' works fine, which means you dont have to worry if you app name changes over time.

Cheers, Charlie

Comment: I recommend to remove country from the link, then users from other countries will have no problem with opening it. http://itunes.apple.com/app/appName/id346542660?mt=8

Comment: Thanks Shmidt - great point.  And for all those fellow QAs out there.. I retested the new URL (without gb) on Mac & iPhone for Twitter, Facebook, Email and SMS

Comment: Furthermore, if you use the iTunes Affiliate program, linking with the iTunes canonical link as you suggested will not only open the iTunes Preview page on the desktop but it will force open the iTunes store to the app page.  Without the affiliate link parameters you can simply append "ls=1" to any link and it will force open the store on the desktop.  https://itunes.apple.com/app/appName/id346542660?mt=8&ls=1

Answer (score 4):

https://itunes.apple.com/app/id##app-id##?mt=8

Replace `##app-id##` with real app-id.

For example:

```
https://itunes.apple.com/app/id346542660?mt=8
```

### Summary

1. No country code. Ex: `gb`
2. No `appName`, only `app-id`.
3. `https` protocol.

Answer (score 3):

URL/Link to an app on the app store can be created very easily but there are several ways to achieve the end result. First of all we need to be clear on the purpose of the link (For ex. link might be used for Facebook posts or used inside an app for urging users to rate the app through in-app alerts/buttons). We can broadly categorize how we will use the link in 3 categories:

**1.** We want to use the link publicly outside the iOS (or OS X) domain. Means you can use this link to share on your Facebook wall or you want to embed the link in mail. I said outside iOS domain because your friends who doesn't have iPhone (or any other iOS device) or MacBook they might also use click that link from Facebook or their mail app/client.
**2.** We want to use the link inside iOS (or OS X) domain. Means when we are certain that our link will be clicked by device using iOS or OS X.
**3.** We want to send the app user (already a user of our app) to specific section (like review section) of the app on app store.

For **category 1 and 2** it's best to use this type of URL:
https://itunes.apple.com/app/dots-a-game-about-connecting/id632285588?mt=8
When you embed this link then it can result in several outcomes:

- If user clicks on this link from iPhone (from any iPhone app or mail app on iPhone): Your app page on App Store will open directly
- If user clicks on this link from any Android Phone or Browser (Chrome/Safari/etc.): Your app page on itunes.apple.com website will open inside default browser. Even if you are opening it on you MacBook it won't open iTunes App Store but will display you app page in Browser itself.

Side Note: There are several places on web where below mentioned sort of link is also suggested: 
http://appstore.com/dotsagameaboutconnecting
When you embed this link then it can result in several outcomes:

- If user clicks on this link from iPhone or MacBook: Your app page on App Store will open directly. So this link is a bit better for MacBook users as it send users of MacBook directly to iTunes instead of staying within Safari browser.
- If user clicks on this link from any Android Phone or Browser (Chrome/Safari/etc.): If user is clicking from PC that has iTunes installed then this link will open your app on iTunes else (on Android devices and PC that doesn't have iTunes) it will open a Apple.com page displaying "Download iTunes" without any mention of your app. Screenshot of that page below:

[image: iTunes not installed. Download iTunes.]

So If you are not sure about who will click on your link (outside/inside iOS domain) or If you want to be on safer side then I recommend first approach. Read [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1633/_index.html) on how to create specific link for your app.

For **category 3** simply use below code in some function/action:

```
NSString *myAppID = @"632285588";
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=%@", myAppID];
//iOS7 doesn't approve above format so add iOS7 specific format
if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.0) {
    url = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"itms-apps://itunes.apple.com/app/id%@", myAppID];
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]];
```

For details on above code see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3654144/direct-rate-in-itunes-link-in-my-app) answer.

For developers who are developing first version of app and app is still not published on app store there is always a quandary about how to get the right link for your to be published app. For that:
Get your app ID from iTunesConnect. Use iTunesConnect to create  your new app - give it a name, description, icon, screenshots, etc. Once app is created on iTunesConnect (without even submitting the app), you can get the Apple ID from the Identifiers section for the app.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have any problems with the following one:

`http://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/notebookpro/id<APP_ID>?mt=8`

I believe, it will be opened on all major browsers/OS.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the itms-apps: approach in our app, which also allows you to select to which "section" of your app the user will land.

So if you want to show them the **reviews**, this is what I use: `itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?type=Purple+Software&id=XXXXXXX`

and for **updating** to the latest version of our app: `itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftwareUpdate?id=XXXXXXX&mt=8`

Comment: My concern with this suggestion is that you only harm your SEO - linking to the same item in the App Store using obscure link structures only pushes down your ability to be discovered in a simple Google Search.  Im curious if that is a concern for you?  You said you use these links only in your app - so do you not link like this on the web?  In social media?  In emails?

Comment: For our web links we use the itunes suggested links. This is purely for the ios app

Comment: The "itms-apps://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewContentsUserReviews?..." approach for in-app review links doesn't work anymore with iOS 7. Sigh...